# Having issue while using soap4r, unable to add namespace, encoding style to soap envelope

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl, soap4r

I am having problems with one of the soap service I'm using. I am using `soap4r` for consuming the soap service. But somehow they are expecting something else than what I am sending. This is what I'm sending:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <env:Header>
        <authenticate env:mustUnderstand="0">
          <username>USERNAME</username>
          <apiKey>API_KEY</apiKey>
        </authenticate>
        <SoftLayer_Network_Media_Transcode_AccountInitParameters env:mustUnderstand="0">
          <id>ID</id>
        </SoftLayer_Network_Media_Transcode_AccountInitParameters>
        <SoftLayer_Network_Media_Transcode_AccountObjectFilter env:mustUnderstand="0">
          <transcodeJobs>
            <transcodeStatus>
              <name>
                <operation>Complete</operation>
              </name>
            </transcodeStatus>
          </transcodeJobs>
        </SoftLayer_Network_Media_Transcode_AccountObjectFilter>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <n1:getTranscodeJobs xmlns:n1="http://api.service.softlayer.com/soap/v3/"
        env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    </n1:getTranscodeJobs>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Which does not return the desired output. What they are expecting is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:n1="http://api.service.softlayer.com/soap/v3/"
        env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <env:Header>
        <authenticate env:mustUnderstand="0">
          <username>USER_NAME</username>
          <apiKey>API_KEY</apiKey>
        </authenticate>
        <SoftLayer_Network_Media_Transcode_AccountInitParameters env:mustUnderstand="0">
          <id>id</id>
        </SoftLayer_Network_Media_Transcode_AccountInitParameters>
        <n1:SoftLayer_Network_Media_Transcode_AccountObjectFilter env:mustUnderstand="0">
          <transcodeJobs>
            <transcodeStatus>
              <name>
                <operation>Complete</operation>
              </name>
            </transcodeStatus>
          </transcodeJobs>
        </n1:SoftLayer_Network_Media_Transcode_AccountObjectFilter>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <n1:getTranscodeJobs >
    </n1:getTranscodeJobs>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

namespace and encoding style in the root (as they are using it in the header ObjectFilter). soap4r is generating the previous request, and i am not able to change it to the later one which actually works.

Here is how I am using soap4r:

```
class SLHeader < SOAP::Header::SimpleHandler
  def initialize(tag, out)
    @out = out
    super(XSD::QName.new(nil, tag))
  end
  def on_simple_outbound
    @out
  end
end
SOAP_WSDL_ENDPOINT = "endpoint"
service = "service name"
initParams = {'id' => ID}
objectFilter = {'transcodeJobs' => {'transcodeStatus' => {'name' => {'operation' => STATUS}}}}
driver = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(SOAP_WSDL_ENDPOINT + service + "?wsdl").create_rpc_driver
driver.headerhandler << SLHeader.new('authenticate', {'username' => @auth_user, 'apiKey' => @auth_key})
driver.headerhandler << SLHeader.new(service + 'InitParameters', initParam)
driver.headerhandler << SLHeader.new(service + 'ObjectFilter', objectFilter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **strongly** recommend that you don't waste too much time with `soap4r`.

If it works, then it's great. But if your SOAP service has particular expectations or is broken in some way, then it is absolutely useless (and impossible to fix without a large amount of monkey patches). The internal state of the library is also pretty bad, and it doesn't work in Ruby 1.9.

For SOAP interfaces I have started using [`handsoap`](http://github.com/unwire/handsoap), which allows you to manually construct SOAP messages that are exactly how your service expects them to be. It's a little more work, but it has saved me a lot of headaches similar to yours. It also works in Ruby 1.9. I have not looked back.

Comment: can you point me to some elaborative tutorials, as I am new to Soap as well as handsoap.

Comment: @bhups, the wiki is a great start, see: http://wiki.github.com/unwire/handsoap/recommendations